# Multiple image upload in Django admin

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-models, django-admin

I am having a lot of trouble trying to code the correct model to upload multiple images to my Django app. I want to be able to upload these images via the django admin. I have tried using ImageField but it only allows one pic at a time and I also want to be able to resize the image.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    DRAFT = 'draft'
    PUBLISHED = 'published'

    CHOICES_STATUS = (
        (DRAFT, 'Draft'),
        (PUBLISHED, 'Published')
    )

    ARTICLE = 'article'
    QUIZ = 'quiz'

    CHOICES_LESSON_TYPE = (
        (ARTICLE, 'Article'),
        (QUIZ, 'Quiz')
    )

    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='lessons', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    long_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICES_STATUS, default=PUBLISHED)
    lesson_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICES_LESSON_TYPE, default=ARTICLE)
```

Serializer.py:

```
class LessonListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'short_description', 'long_description')
```

Admin.py:

```
class LessonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'course', 'status', 'lesson_type']
    list_filter = ['status', 'lesson_type']
    search_fields = ['title', 'short_description', 'long_description']
    inlines = [LessonCommentInline]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want multiple images you need to create another table for images (One2Many relationship).

`pip install --upgrade Pillow` # if needed

```
# import PIL for image resizing
from PIL import Image

class Photo(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to ='photos/')

    # resizing the image, you can change parameters like size and quality.
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       img = Image.open(self.photo.path)
       if img.height > 1125 or img.width > 1125:
           img.thumbnail((1125,1125))
       img.save(self.photo.path,quality=70,optimize=True)
```

And for the admin you can do:

###### admin.py

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Photo

class LessonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PhotoAdmin]

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson


admin.site.register(Photo)
admin.site.register(Lesson, LessonAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks @lucutzu33, but can I add another admin class within the LessonAdmin inlines? I am already using it for LessonCommentInline.

Comment: Of course, that's a list.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Its definitely working. I am a noob with Django and Vue.js. Im having trouble showing the images on the frontend but I can upload multiple files in the admin section. Do I need to add 'photo' to Lesson serializer.py and call the photo  with {{ lesson.photo }} ??

Comment: Yes, something like that: `photos = PhotoSerializers(read_only=True, many=True)`